# How to speed up this conversion function?

Tags: performance, delphi, loops

I have this function called `IntToStrLen` which converts an integer to a string of a padded size. For example, an integer value of `42` with a size of `4` would result in a string `__42` (padded with a given character, space by default).

The problem is when this function is used in bulk (for example 1,000,000 times in a loop), it adds extra weight onto the loop. The loop I'm using this in, without this function, takes about 20 seconds, but with this function, I'm still waiting as of right now for this function to complete, after about 5 minutes.

How can I speed up the following function?

```
function IntToStrLen(const Value: Integer; const Len: Integer;
  const Fill: String = ' '): String;
var
  T: String;
begin
  Result:= IntToStr(Value);                      //convert result
  if Length(Result) > Len then
    Result:= Copy(Result, 1, Len)                //forcefully truncate
  else if Length(Result) < Len then begin
    T:= '';
    while Length(T) < (Len - Length(Result)) do  //fill space with character
      T:= T + Fill;
    Result:= T + Result;                         //return combination
  end;
end;
```

Comment: FWIW, your code does not initialize `T` before you read it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan strings are initialized you know

Comment: @StefanGlienke In certain scenarios

Comment: Either you have a typo or your bottleneck is elsewhere.

Comment: @JerryDodge I all scenarios a local variable of a managed type gets initialized and this is what we are talking about here, right?

Comment: @StefanGlienke Yes they are, but semantically I don't really like that. Obviously if perf matters then you may choose to rely on it.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Actually I was mistakenly thinking of function results not being initialized, which can lead to obscure results when a function is used in a loop.

Comment: @JerryDodge Not by the routine at least - but they have a defined value.

Comment: @StefanGlienke `function GetText: String; begin Result:= Result + 'Text'; end;` and then `for X := 1 to 4 do begin ShowMessage(GetText); end;` should demonstrate why function results should be initialized. The function's result never gets reset back to blank, so it keeps adding onto the same string.

Comment: @stefan Jerry's example is sound. Leaving variables uninitialized requires a deep understanding of implementation details.

Comment: @JerryDodge I am very aware of this issue - I suggest you vote for http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=32556

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The absolute number one change that you can make here is to avoid heap allocations. Your code presently has multiple heap allocations. Your goal here is to write a function with zero heap allocations.

That means you need the caller to allocate and provide the buffer. Typically they will do so with a stack allocated buffer, which hence costs nothing to allocate (or deallocate). If the caller really needs a `string`, which is always allocated on the heap, then the caller can wrap your function with a call to `SetString`.

The function prototype might look like this:

```
procedure IntToStrLen(const Value, Len: Integer; var Buffer: array of Char;
  const Fill: Char = ' ');
```

The first point to stress here is that `Fill` must be a `Char`. Your use of `string` is inefficient and allows the caller to call a fill "character" with length not equal to one. Doing so would of course break your function because it would return a value with length not equal to `Len`.

Do note also that the implementation must not call `IntToStr` because that involves heap allocation. So you need to write your own heap allocation free integer to decimal text conversion code because, astonishingly, the RTL does not offer such functionality. When I do this I use code like so:

```
procedure DivMod(Dividend, Divisor: Cardinal; 
  out Quotient, Remainder: Cardinal);
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
asm
        PUSH  EBX
        MOV   EBX,EDX
        XOR   EDX,EDX
        DIV   EBX
        MOV   [ECX],EAX
        MOV   EBX,Remainder
        MOV   [EBX],EDX
        POP   EBX
end;
{$ELSE IF Defined(CPUX64)}
asm
        .NOFRAME
        MOV   EAX,ECX
        MOV   ECX,EDX
        XOR   EDX,EDX
        DIV   ECX
        MOV   [R8],EAX
        MOV   [R9],EDX
end;
{$ELSE}
  {$Message Error 'Unrecognised platform.'}
{$ENDIF}

function CopyIntegerToCharBuffer(const Value: Integer; 
  var Buffer: array of Char): Integer;
var
  i, j: Integer;
  val, remainder: Cardinal;
  negative: Boolean;
  tmp: array [0..15] of Char;
begin
  negative := Value<0;
  val := abs(Value);
  Result := 0;
  repeat
    DivMod(val, 10, val, remainder);
    tmp[Result] := Chr(remainder + ord('0'));
    inc(Result);
  until val=0;
  if negative then begin
    tmp[Result] := '-';
    inc(Result);
  end;
  Assert(Result<=Length(Buffer));

  i := 0;
  j := Result-1;
  while i<Result do begin
    Buffer[i] := tmp[j];
    inc(i);
    dec(j);
  end;
end;
```

Now you can make decimal text representations of integers without touching the heap. From there it's a short way to your function.

```
procedure IntToStrLen(const Value, Len: Integer; var Buffer: array of Char;
  const Fill: Char = ' ');
var
  tmp: array [0..15] of Char;
  i, N: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Length(Buffer)>=Len);
  N := CopyIntegerToCharBuffer(Value, tmp);
  if N>=Len then begin
    Move(tmp, Buffer, SizeOf(Char)*Len);
  end else begin
    for i := 0 to Len-N-1 do begin
      Buffer[i] := Fill;
    end;
    Move(tmp, Buffer[Len-N], SizeOf(Char)*N);
  end;
end;
```

At this point you'll have gained the bulk of the available performance benefits. From here on in you will be into diminishing returns. You could micro-optimise `CopyIntegerToCharBuffer` as is done in `SysUtils._IntToStr32` for instance. Beyond that I'm sure the implementation of `IntToStrLen` could be optimised with judicious use of assembler. But such optimisations will yield nothing like the benefit you have gained so far from avoiding the heap.

Of course, all this assumes that you have correctly identified your performance bottleneck. It's all too easy to assume that you know where the performance bottleneck is by statically analysing the code. Unless you've actually profiled it carefully expect to find that your intuition is a poor judge of where to invest optimisation effort.

Comment: Astronomical improvement, greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use shortstring here as the return value of the function? Or am I missing something that would slow things down? +1 for considering non intel processors.

Comment: @Johan A shortstring could perhaps work. But then you'd need to convert from 8 bit to 16 bit text encoding down the line. And I did not consider non-Intel processors. You'd need to write a new `DivMod` for ARM!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are there some general guidelines how to avoid heap allocations?

Comment: @user3060326 The first thing I would say is that only attempt something like the code in my answer if it will have discernible benefit. It does make the code unreadable. That's quite a price to pay so there needs to be real benefit. Obvious places where heap allocation happens is with strings, dynamic arrays, instances of classes. Step 1 is always to profile to identify bottlenecks. Only then do you consider how to optimise.

Answer (score 3):

Try this variant
(and you don't treat negative numbers)

```
function IntToStrLen(const Value: Integer; const Len: Integer;
  const Fill: Char = ' '): String;
var
  T: String;
begin
  Result:= IntToStr(Value);                     
  if Length(Result) > Len then
    SetLength(Result, Len)                //forcefully truncate
  else if Length(Result) < Len then 
    Result := StringOfChar(Fill, Len - Length(Result)) + Result;
end;
```

**P.S.** So strange truncation (2014=>20)  - is what you really want?

Comment: Still taking a while, but I need to create a test grounds to clock the speed - because my current testing is loading / reading a large binary file at the moment. It's converting every byte in a 20mb file into a string and displaying it in a byte grid.

Comment: Displaying a big table can take a lot of time. Who wants to look at 20 millions numbers?

Comment: For the nature of its implementation, the result *must* be the exact specified length, truncating it is of course not elegant, but it's the only way to make sure it's perfect length.

Comment: For all you know I might be designing the Matrix :-)

Comment: I've tested. Our functions work 5-20 seconds for Len=10 and 20 millions numbers on old Athlon processor (empty function with the only operator SetLength(Result) works 2 s), so there is another time eater in your program